# How to exit function early if outputs are not requested?

Tags: function, matlab, return, output

I'm writing a function that has multiple inputs and outputs.
*All* the outputs are only needed on infrequent occasions.
Moreover, some inputs are only used to generate some of the infrequent outputs.

A simplified example might clarify:

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out1 = inp1 + inp2;          % only requires inp1 and inp2
out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;   % requires all inputs
end
```

If I run `a = foo(1, 2);` I would naively expect this to work: since `out2` is not requested, `inp3` should not be required (and I would expect the program to terminate after the first line). However, this results in an error and stops the progression of the code.

My question is: what is the easiest way to circumvent this? Is there inbuilt functionality or a known design pattern used to mitigate this issue? Ideally, it wouldn't require any nesting. Similar examples happen in multiple places throughout the code, and so the solution would ideally be amenable to repetition too.

---

Possible solutions:

Checking the inputs/outputs is doable but is not amenable to repetition. For example

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out1 = inp1 + inp2;          % only requires inp1 and inp2
if nargout > 1
  out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3; % requires all inputs
end
end
```

would result in a lot of nesting if multiple conditions were tested in this way.

Using `return` could be start of the solution, but is not ideal:

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out1 = inp1 + inp2;          % only requires inp1 and inp2
if nargout < 2; return; end
out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;   % requires all inputs
end
```

(is this the best way?)

The ideal solution would also be invariant to the position of the arguments. e.g.

```
[~,b] = baz(1, 2);

function [out1, out2] = baz(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out2 = inp1 + inp2;          % only requires inp1 and inp2
out1 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;   % requires all inputs
end
```

should also run without error.

Comment: “What is the best way?” — whichever option **you** think is more readable. —— as for your last question, just order the outputs from least work to most work. A typical solution for returning an arbitrary subset of possible outputs is to include as input argument a list of required outputs by name: `[out1, out4] = func(x, y, ['out1','out4'])`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid an expensive computation to produce an output that was not requested, then you must include a check on `nargout`, there's no other way to avoid the computation.

Some functions produce as many outputs as inputs - in those cases, use `varargin` and `varargout`. But in general, I would say it's probably an awkward design if a particular output can only be computed based on the number of inputs provided.

An alternative might be to use an [`arguments` block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html) to specify default values for input parameters.

```matlab
function [out1, out2] = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
arguments
    inp1
    inp2
    inp3 = 0
end
out1 = inp1 + inp2;
out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;
end
```

Comment: i dig the `arguments` usage, it is quite the clean solution if you have a fixed number or inputs.

Comment: You can use `arguments` with repeating inputs, and it's pretty neat with name-value pairs too. (I'm still getting used to it, but it's great at getting rid of all the different ugly ways of dealing with optional inputs)

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any way to use this kind of approach in a position-agnostic manner (e.g. the last code block in my question)?

Comment: And I know it is a bit older, but I am a big fan of `inputParser` - works well, and has compatibility with older versions of MATLAB.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you want to optionally not calculate the first output, by specifying `~`. There's no way to do that. You might be better off restructuring your code so that clients can compose the computations they want themselves. Or else, implement and object with methods to extract the different results - this can then ensure computations aren't repeated.

Comment: @Edric pretty sure is doable by going through a circuitous route ( please check the edit on my answer and tell my what do you think)

Comment: One more thing about this approach - the code will run without error, but it doesn't actually stop the computation of the extraneous outputs.

Answer (score 3):

You can just check the number of output arguments requested and `return` from the function before the point where your additional inputs would be required to form the unrequested outputs

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out1 = inp1 + inp2;          % only requires inp1 and inp2
% If only one output is requested then stop here
if nargout < 2
    return
end
% More than one output requested, calculate further outputs (requires further inputs)
out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;   % requires all inputs
end
```

This works as described, if you call `a = foo(1,2)` you get `a=3` and no error.

Edit: from your comment it sounds more like you want to populate as many outputs as possible for the given inputs. It's not possible to detect which outputs are discarded using `~` without some sort of parsing of the calling line (see [this answer](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/580671-can-a-function-known-whether-which-specific-output-is-ignored-tilde-operator#answer_495106) on MathWorks Answers ref [detectoutputsuppression](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/79218-detectoutputsuppression)). So a `nargout` approach isn't sufficient to handle the `[~,b] = foo(1,2,3)` case.

So in this case in which case I'd probably just use a cell array as a single output:

```
function out = foo(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out = cell(1,2); % Initialise output with two (empty) elements

out{1} = inp1 + inp2;
if nargin > 2
    out{2} = inp1 + inp2 + inp3; 
end
end
```

Then if you only need the 2nd output you can use `out=foo(1,2,3); out{2}`

A final alternative could just be to make the first input dictate the behaviour of the function, i.e.

```
function [out1, out2] = foo(nout, inp1, inp2, inp3)
% nout should be 1, 2, or [1,2] depending on the requested outputs to save
% on computation time for undesired outputs
if any(nout == 1)
   out1 = inp1 + inp2;
end
if any(nout == 2)
    out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3; 
end
end
```

This would save on computing unrequired outputs and is fairly explicit. Obviously it requires a little more awareness on the line where `foo` is called, as it would be used like

```
a = foo( 1, 1, 2 ); % only want output 1
                    % equivalent to a = foo( 1, 1, 2, 3 )
[~,b] = foo( 2, 1, 2, 3 ); % only want output 2
                    % No computation time spend on output 1
[a,b] = foo( [1,2], 1, 2 ,3 ); % compute both outputs
[a,b] = foo( [1,2], 1, 2 ); % errors because not enough inputs to compute b
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any way to use this kind of approach in a position-agnostic manner (e.g. the last code block in my question)?

Comment: @magnesium I've elaborated on my answer

Comment: this solution could lead to an obnoxious amount of if-else statements if the inputs are numerous no?

Comment: @FerroLuca Sure it could, the whole premise of this question is to conditionally execute a function differently depending on different combinations of inputs, I don't see how any answer would avoid an increasing amount of `if-else` statements. My actual advice would be to move the two calculations (in this case) into separate functions, but that's not what the OP wants to achieve. I'm assuming their addition example is a dummy placeholder and the actual function is complex, in which case defaulting an input to 0 might not be sufficient.

Comment: yeah i see, re-evaluating the code and problem structure seems to be the better solution from every perspective

Comment: The cell array output doesn’t solve any problems, it doesn’t stop computing the first unwanted output. And requiring `nout` as first input argument is redundant, it’s the same value as `nargout`. But the first part of the answer is good. :)

Comment: @cris the `nout` option is specifically to address OP's query about only computing the 2nd output when the function is called like `[~,b] = ...` which can't be achieved with `nargout`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the `nout` example. It lists the requested outputs. That works. Though typically I’ve seen that using strings rather than numbers, because that makes the code using the function easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the built-in 'variable arguments input' , `varargin` (docs [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)) in combination with `nargin` (docs [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html?searchHighlight=nargin&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_nargin)) and 'variable arguments output `varargout` (docs [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html))

```
function [out1, varargout] = foo(inp1, inp2, varargin)
if nargin < 3
out1 = inp1 + inp2;
else        % only requires inp1 and inp2
out1 = inp1 + inp2;
varargout{1}= inp1 + inp2 + varargin{1};   
end
end
```

Play around with them and see if you can figure the solution you want.
If you have a lot of inputs a `switch-case` or some cascading `if-else` will be needed.

---

For the position-agnostic topic an idea similar to this can be implemented:

Assuming the operation carried out is bound to I/Os numbers in such a way that output n = sum inputs from 1 to n+1

```
function varargout=foo(varargin)
if nargin == nargout+1
if nargout >1
historypath = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
cmd= historypath(end);
otps=extractBetween(cmd.toCharArray','[',']');
otps=strsplit(otps{1},',');
else
    otps={'pass'};
end
for tt=1:nargout
        if strcmp(otps{tt},'~')
            varargout{tt}=NaN;
        else
            varargout{tt}=sum([varargin{1:tt+1}]);
        end
   
end
else
    error('Mismatched I/Os')
end
end
```

This function parses the command window call of the function to bypass the '~' outputs.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any way to use this kind of approach in a position-agnostic manner (e.g. the last code block in my question)?

Comment: i understand what you are trying to do but i see no point in doing it since you can control how it is called and avoid the problem at source. Could you elaborate a case in which it makes sense? ( it is quite the design pickle, could take some convolute complex the code and some time to write it that's why i ask)

Comment: In this case, there is a large computation which has several steps. Generally, this computation is the most important - so it makes sense for it to be the default output. However, sometimes you might want the results from the intermediate step only (without the whole computation). In this instance, you would want to return the second argument early, without doing the whole computation. 

One solution would be to make the intermediate steps their own functions, but I am trying to do this so that you can call the same function each time, and the computations are done efficiently.

Comment: oh i see, interesting approach. The thing is that to be able to  get `[~,b]` working, the first output must be calculated anyways. You could assign a placeholder value as `NaN` to it though. I'll edit the answer to include my idea

Comment: This means of not computing ignored outputs works only at the command-line, and uses undocumented features - liable to be removed with zero notice. I would not rely on this!

Comment: the command window limitation is indeed a big one you are correct, also is clearly bad code. I would 100% reconsider the structure and functionalities of the problem to avoid such implementation. Still it's cool that it can be done, no? Anyways it is documented here: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93265-how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-last-expression-typed-in-the-matlab-command-window-in-matlab-7

Answer (score 1):

For each output create an anonymous function and place them in a cell array and use `arrayfun` to generate the outputs:

```
function varargout = foo(varargin)
    fcn = {                                    ...
        @(inp1, inp2) inp1 + inp2,             ...
        @(inp1, inp2, inp3) inp1 + inp2 + inp3 ...
        };
    varargout = arrayfun(1:nargout, @(n){fcn{n}(varargin{:})});
end
```

If an output is requested the first function is executed. If two outputs are requested both functions are executed:

```
a = foo(1, 2);        % only the first function is executed
[a,b] = foo(1, 2, 3);  % both functions are executed
```

Note that instead of anonymous functions you can define local functions and place their handles in the cell array:

```
function out1 = foo2(inp1, inp2)
    out1 = inp1 + inp2;
end

function out2 = foo3(inp1, inp2, inp3)
    out2 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;
end

function varargout = foo(varargin)
    fcn = {@foo2, @foo3};
    varargout = arrayfun(1:nargout, @(n){fcn{n}(varargin{:})});
end
```

Comment: That only works if the outputs are independent, which is unlikely given that it’s a single function computing them. It’s also a lot more obscure syntactically (harder to read) than a simple “if nargin < 2 then return”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I personally prefer `if statement`. However this solution may be useful for those that are against `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Wolfie, Ferro Luca and Edric: I think another solution is to check the existence/emptiness of the input arguments, and then return early if some values do not exist. An advantage of this is that (i) it allows checks of each variable; (ii) it does not require nesting if multiple checks need to be done.

```
function [out1, out2] = baz(inp1, inp2, inp3)
out1 = NaN;
out2 = inp1 + inp2;                      % only requires inp1 and inp2
if ~exist('inp3', 'var'); return; end    % check if data are present for next steps 
out1 = inp1 + inp2 + inp3;               % requires all inputs
end
```